# If else statements to

Tags: r, var

I have some trouble creating new columns from existing columns.

What I want to achieve is:

1) For rows where **treatment** equals "*mixed*", I want to locate the NA and then;

2a) If the NA is under *pun1* or *pun2* then;

the integer of *eva3* and *eva4* must be converted/copied to *eva_out1* and *eva_out2*, respectively,

2b) Vice versa, if NA is under *pun3* or *pun4*, then;

*eva1* equals to *eva_out1*, where *eva2* also has its integer converted to *eva_out2*

**We will never have `eva_out3` because of the dyadic group composition.**

At first I tried this:

```
df5$eva_out1 <-  with(df5, ifelse(
    (is.na(pun1) | is.na(pun2)) & treatment == "mixed",
    df5$eva_out1 <- eva3,NA ))
```

Which gets most of the job done, but I can't run this multiple times, because other values would be overwritten by the other block of code that goes up for *eva_out2*.

Then I tried this:

```
  df5$eva_out1 <-  with(df5, ifelse(
  (is.na(pun1) | is.na(pun2)) & treatment == "mixed",
  df5$eva_out1 == eva2 & df5$eva_out2 == eva3, ifelse(
  (is.na(pun3) | is.na(pun4)) & treatment == "mixed",
  df5$eva_out1 == eva1 & df5$eva_out2 == eva2, NA )))
```

And this

```
if(df5$treatment == "mixed") {
} if ( is.na(pun1) | is.na(pun2) ) {
  eva_out1 <- eva3 & eva_out2 <- eva4 
} else if ( is.na(pun3) | is.na(pun4) ) { 
  eva_out1 <- eva1 & eva_out2 <- eva2
} else { 
  eva_out1 <- NULL & eva_out2 <- NULL
}
```

But both either spew errors or do not give the results I need.
I've been looking at functions, but ifelse() seems more legit in this situation. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

First 12 rows of the data:

```
.     UniqueSS subject group   part   round  treatment pun1 pun2 pun3 pun4 eva1 eva2 eva3
1        11       1     1 punishment     0 homogenous   NA    0    0    0    0    0    0
2        12       2     1 punishment     0 homogenous    0   NA    0    0    0    0    0
3        13       3     1 punishment     0 homogenous    0    0   NA    0    0    0    1
4        14       4     1 punishment     0 homogenous    0    0    1   NA    0    0    0
5        11       1     1 punishment     1 homogenous   NA    0    0    0    0    0    0
6        12       2     1 punishment     1 homogenous    0   NA    0    0    0    0    0
7        13       3     1 punishment     1 homogenous    0    0   NA    0    0    0    0
8        14       4     1 punishment     1 homogenous    0    0    0   NA    0    0    0
9        11       1     1 punishment     2 homogenous   NA    0    0    0    0    0    0
10       12       2     1 punishment     2 homogenous    0   NA    0    0    0    0    0
11       13       3     1 punishment     2 homogenous    0    0   NA    0    0    0    0
12       14       4     1 punishment     2 homogenous    0    0    0   NA    0    0    0
```

For the third row we would have columns `eva_out1 == 0`, `eva_out2 == 0`, because member *pun4* is in the same category group as *pun3* and thus may not be converted to another column.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not knowing R, I assume all the code shown is R. What does this question have to do with Python?

Comment: @chepner It got the tag by accident, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand but is this what you're after?

```
df5$eva_out_1 <- df5$eva_out_2 <- NA

cond1 <- df5$treatment == "mixed" & (is.na(df5$pun1) | is.na(df5$pun2))
df5$eva_out_1[cond1] <- df5$eva3[cond1]
df5$eva_out_2[cond1] <- df5$eva4[cond1]

cond2 <- df5$treatment == "mixed" & (is.na(df5$pun3) | is.na(df5$pun4))
df5$eva_out_1[cond2] <- df5$eva1[cond2]
df5$eva_out_2[cond2] <- df5$eva2[cond2]
```

Comment: Hi, I had to rearrange the data to make it work, but I managed. Thanks, it was a really weird problem to solve :)